# Where does Xcode store whatever it downloads from devices?

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash-reports

When I attach an unrecognized iPhone to Xcode, it downloads some information from it. (I believe this includes debugging information.) Where does it store this information on my Mac's file system?

I would check myself, but I ran out of devices to throw at it before realizing I didn't know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Xcode 4 and 5 store device symbols in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport

Answer (score 0):

The usual place is:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/<firmware_version>/Symbols
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept this as soon as it lets me. :) In the meantime, do you know if the symbols are model specific? (I always thought they were, but it looks like they're just per OS.)

Comment: The symbols are firmware specific